# Django - Flickr feed without sync

Tags: django, flickr

I want to show the latest 8 images from a Flickr photostream using Django. I've had a good google and the only articles I can find focus on syncing the results with a database. I'd rather not do this if possible, I just want to show the images and nothing else.

http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/FlickrIntegration This page has some adaptable code, but the library he uses seems to be offline now.

Does anyone have any examples of how I might integrate with a flickr stream without syncing the results?

Comment: what about fetching and integrating the rss feed?

Comment: That could work. Trying to find some examples of parsing RSS in django

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you just use the flickr API from Python? There's probably python packages to do it. All you do is get the user's photostream info, map the photos to URLS:

http://www.flickr.com/services/api/flickr.people.getPhotos.html

Then your Django template just has an <img> tag with the right URL.

Edit: python packages listed on the flickr API page:

http://stuvel.eu/flickrapi

http://code.google.com/p/flickrpy/

Answer (score 1):

I made [Flickr Pony](https://github.com/ZuluPro/flickr-pony) for use Flickr with [Django Storage API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/files/storage/) and more.

You'll only need [an API KEY](https://www.flickr.com/services/apps/create/apply/?) and launch this:

```
>>> from flickr_pony.storage import FlickrStorage
>>> storage = FlickrStorage(api_key="myApiKey")
>>> storage.listdir('140893176@N07')
([], ['https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1586/25309081103_518e989396_o.jpg',
 'https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1623/25911906696_84c8cf31ae_o.jpg',
 'https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1617/25637193860_98a08d224f_o.jpg',
 ...
 'https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1671/25794942526_5b54c8a908_o.jpg',
 'https://farm2.staticflickr.com/1653/25820730145_4040532d03_o.jpg'])
```